# Should the question “Why can’t I accept my own answer?” be undeleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, blog, historical-lock

I just came across a blog post titled [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) on the Stack Overflow blog. It links to a now-deleted question on the main site titled [Why can’t I accept my own answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206541/why-cant-i-accept-my-own-answer).

I understand why this question was deleted (this discussion should have happened on Meta). I also understand that Stack Overflow-the-community isn’t responsible for making sure decade-old links on the blog keep working. In this case, however, because the question presumably has historical significance, I propose the following:

- that the question be undeleted
- that it be immediately closed
- that it be locked as a question with historical significance (like, for example, [What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184618/what-is-the-best-comment-in-source-code-you-have-ever-encountered))

Comment: It's a blog post from 2009. Things have changed a bit since then. There is no historical significance to something that is a product of its time.

Comment: "that it be immediately closed" The question seems to be already closed, as a duplicate of a target that isn't linked anymore.

Comment: Closed as a duplicate of a target that *never was* linked, in fact. The system was quite a bit stupider back in those days. :-)

Comment: "*that it be immediately closed*" well, it was closed about 20 minutes after it was posted. asked 2008-10-15 21:16:29Z and closed 2008-10-15 21:35:55Z. So, that is already done.

Comment: I don’t know if or when it was closed since I don’t have enough rep to view it.

Comment: The deleted question seems to have been closed as a duplicate before deletion, but I don't see any sign of what it was purportedly a duplicate *of*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The ["Accept Your Own Answers"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) blog post does not link to the deleted Q&A. It links to [this other blog post, "Why Can’t I Accept My Own Answer?"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/12/01/why-cant-i-accept-my-own-answer/), and *that one* links to [the deleted Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/206541). Therefore, no information is lost. The deleted Q&A isn't what Jeff is referring to when he says:

> I was initially very much against this, but several commenters in the [Why Can’t I Accept My Own Answer?](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/why-cant-i-accept-my-own-answer) post convinced me that, with a few rule tweaks, it *could* work.

They're comments on *the linked blog post*, not on the deleted Q&A. The deleted Q&A is just an example he's giving of how the question often comes up. There's nothing insightful in that deleted Q&A. Judge for yourself:

[image: Screenshot of entire deleted Q&A.]

It would make more sense to delete the link from the words "a lot" in the blog post, rather than to undelete the Q&A.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer! Thinking about it, if the question did have some value, it presumably would have been noticed by someone else undeleted already. (By the way, I don’t have to be *that* worried about downvotes on MSO, right?)

Comment: Considering it was deleted by Jeff Atwood himself (the author of the blog post), he probably wouldn't have done so if he thought it would make the blog post any less clear. And, no, downvotes on MSO don't affect your rep or harm you in any way. Although they *can* mean that a post is problematic or excessively low-quality, they often represent disagreement with something you've proposed (as in this case).

Comment: Now I’ve read the question for myself, I can see why. Thanks again!